# What is the difference between INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql, join

What is the difference between INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN?

The following queries give the same output.

```
SELECT * FROM EMP LEFT JOIN DEPT
ON EMP.EMP_ID = DEPT.EMP_ID

SELECT * FROM EMP INNER JOIN DEPT
ON EMP.EMP_ID = DEPT.EMP_ID
```

`left join` should give only rows from the first table, i.e. `EMP` and not `DEPT`.

Comment: *"only rows from the first table"* = `SELECT * FROM EMP;` :-)

Comment: What is the (1 specific researched non-duplicate) question?

Answer (score 1):

An `INNER JOIN` will only show the rows for which the join clause holds. A `LEFT JOIN` will also show the rows on the 'left' table for which the join clause doesn't hold, and will give null values for the columns of the joined table.

So when doing a left join, it will not decrease the number of records in the result set for the left table, whereas with an inner join it might. However, if the join clause gives at least 1 match in the right table for each row in the left table, the inner join and left join give an equivalent result.